# How do you make an infant sleep on her stomach with her hands on her chin?

Tags: infant, newborn

Have a look at the photo below. Is it a photoshop trick or is it actually possible to make an infant sleep like this?

If it is possible, ***how to go about this pose?***

[This isn't about the camera, this is about the technique of handling the kid]

[image] ([source](https://plus.google.com/u/0/photos/104921346775116248789/albums/5923130107386457505/5923130106327088706?pid=5923130106327088706&oid=104921346775116248789))

Comment: I believe the answer is to start with a sleeping or at least fully-fed and happy baby, put them in the pose, take a ton of pictures none of which are posed right because they moved, put them back in the pose, fire off a ton more, and stop when you finally get the super cute "perfectly natural" one.

Comment: @Chrys - actually that pose is really dangerous to try and do without a spotter.

Comment: It is photo shopped. the mom is usually holding the baby on the top of the head and by the hands. Then the photographer just edits the mom's hands out. Best to let a pro handle these types of pictures, they use heaters to keep the baby warm, they bring all the props, and they know lighting. Most are pretty reasonable.

Comment: I've read about this from both a photography and a medical "angle" and agree: this is for trained professionals only, with spotters, and only doable safely during **very early infancy** (meaning more than a few days out, and you can't do it anymore).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This pose is actually 100% photo-edited. You take a sleeping kid, prop them in two different ways with your hands supporting them, then merge the two different pictures. In the first shot, the photographer or an assistant holds the baby's head. In the second the arms are held. The two shots are merged so that it looks as if no one was holding the baby. But no, it is not really possible to - at least safely - acheive this pose with just a baby. You can find an example of how it is done [here](http://www.elizabethhalford.com/photography-tutorials/photographing/11-top-tips-for-newborn-photography-safety/). You will find that some newborn photographers hate this pose and those like it because it does not really capture how newborns actually are (and can be dangerous if not done right). An example of reasoning why not to pose infants like this is [here](http://rachelvanoven.com/blog/getting-this-off-my-chest/).

Comment: Very helpful links!

Answer (score 7):

Answering the question at the top. You don't. Let them sleep in the most comfortable safe position.

If it is just for taking pictures of your little puppet, follow Chrys's instruction.